# How to 'Turn Off', or 'Override' a Named Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have the following HTML:

```
img class="hoverContact"
img class="hoverContact"
img class="hoverContact"
```

and jQuery code:

```
function highlightContact(ev) {
   $(ev).addClass('lightblue');  
}
function unhighlightContact(ev) {
   $(ev).removeClass('lightblue');  
}
```

and

```
$('.hoverContact').live("mouseover", function(){
    highlightContact(this);
});
$('.hoverContact').live("mouseout", function(){
    unhighlightContact(this);
});
$('.hoverContact').live("click", function(){
    highlightContact(this);
});
```

And I am trying to keep the lightblue class on a click, but obviously when I click I need to mouseaway and it turns off the lightblue class... so I need help figuring out how to override the unhighlight class...

Comment: So what's the behaviour after click? And when does the 'normal' highlighting come back into force?

Comment: @no good..the behavior after is an ajax call...and the image would retain the class until a new one is clicked

Comment: What exactly does adding the `lightblue` class do? Are you using it elsewhere in code, or is it simply used for CSS?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way but I would do it like this - you can set arbitrary properties with jQuery and not screw up your page validation or browser compatibility by sticking data in a randomly named html attribute. The "proper" way to do that is to include another XML namespace on the HTML tag but I've never seen a practical reason to do it.

```
$('.hoverContact').attr('custom:on', '0')
.live("mouseover", function(){
    highlightContact(this);
})
.live("mouseout", function(){
    if ($(this).attr('custom:on') == '0') {
      unhighlightContact(this);
    }
})
.live("click", function(){
    $('.hoverContact').attr('custom:on', '0');
    $(this).attr('custom:on', '1');
    highlightContact(this);
});
```

Comment: this works great but is a little buggy and doesn't work until you click an image...so they all have the class if you hover them all...thoughts? thanks...